# Python Threading: Not getting desired outcome

Tags: python, multithreading

I wrote up a simple threading class that monitors two parameters. I don't get any errors when I command the two thread start commands, however, the call to my second thread doesn't appear to execute. Here is my class:

```
import threading
import time
from SHFramework import SH

class CLSThread():
   def __init__(self):
      self.tsh = SH()
      self.tsh.StartServer()
      self.GetStatusThread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.GetTemperature())
      self.GetStatusThread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.GetX())
   def GetTemperature(self):
      while True:
         temp_val = self.tsh.GetValue("Temperature")
         print("value from {}:".format("Temperature")
         print str(temp_val)
   def GetX(self):
      while True:
         x_val = self.tsh.GetValue("X")
         print("value from {}:".format("X")
         print str(x_val)
clst1 = CLSThread()

clst1.GetStatusThread1.start()
clst2.GetStatusThread2.start()
```

when I command `'clst1.GetStatusThread1.start()'`, it prints out the results from `GetTemperature` just fine. However, I can't tell if it ever commands `GetX` because it never prints out the results from that method. Although, when I get rid of the `while True:` statement from both methods, and only leave the lines that follow, it does print out the results from both methods (`clst1.GetStatusThread1.start()`,`clst2.GetStatusThread2.start()`).

Comment: `target=self.GetTemperature()` you are calling the method immidiately instead of specifying the function as the target (get rid of the `()` at the end, it should be `target=self.GetTemperature`) and then similarly with `GetX`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @ScottHunter this is a common mistake so I'm looking for a duplicate target

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python threads not running in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624962/python-threads-not-running-in-parallel)

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, I have already tried that actually. When I do that, it seems to interfere with my SH() session. I get an error that says I have not commanded a coexistence. For some reason, it seems like it interferes with StartServer(), but I'm not sure how.

Comment: possibly because it doesn't support threading? All I know is that your code currently does not run concurrently and that I have pointed you towards the correct way to run it concurrently. If you are saying that doing it like that gives you issues then that is what you need to be asking about.

Comment: copy all. will look into it. thanks!