# threading with multiple variables

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, import

I do have a small python script that aims to run 2 to 3 function in parallel.
The scripts seems to work because, I do have the answer, however, it ends with an exception:

```
import threading

Variable2="V2"
Variable1="V1"
Variable12="V1"
Variable22="V2"
Variable23="V3"

def func1(Variable1,Variable2):
    print ("This is my  fisrt fucntion ")
    print ("My first variable is : %s ") % (Variable1)
    print ("My second variable is : %s ") % (Variable2)

def func2(Variable12,Variable22,Variable23):
    print ("This is my  fisrt fucntion ")
    print ("My first variable is : %s ") % (Variable12)
    print ("My second variable is : %s ") % (Variable22)
    print ("My third variable is : %s ") % (Variable23)

def runInParallel(*fns):
    proc = []
    for fn, arg in fns:
        p = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(arg,))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()


runInParallel( ( func1(Variable1,Variable2,) ), (func2(Variable12,Variable22,Variable23,) ) )
```

It gives me the following :

```
This is my  fisrt fucntion
My first variable is : V1
My second variable is : V2
This is my  fisrt fucntion
My first variable is : V1
My second variable is : V2
My third variable is : V3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testpara.py", line 69, in <module>
    runInParallel( ( func1(Variable1,Variable2,) ) , (func2(Variable12,Variable22,Variable23,) ) )
File "testpara.py", line 61, in runInParallel
    for fn, arg in fns:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I checked [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) And it seems one of the parameters of the threading is note passing `( group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={} )`.

Any clue?

edit : This seems to be different from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624962/python-threads-not-running-in-parallel) Because variables in that answer is the same one with an updated value.

Comment: Notice that you're not passing the functions to `runInParallel`: you're actually evaluating those functions (both in the main thread, so there's no concurrency here) and passing the *results* of the two functions to `runInParallel`. Since both functions return `None`, you get the error message you're seeing.

Comment: What am I missing ? .. I am not an expert in programming..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python threads not running in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624962/python-threads-not-running-in-parallel)

Comment: Specifically, you're missing two commas. You want: `runInParallel( ( func1, (Variable1,Variable2,) ), (func2, (Variable12,Variable22,Variable23,) ) )`

Comment: I tried this before pasting asking my question here... Same result. Not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mark Dickinson in the comments, you're not calling `runInParallel()` properly, you're actually calling each function in the calling sequence (which results in the return value of each function, `None`, being passed as the arguments' values).

The fix is easy, just change one line in `runInParallel()`, and add some commas when calling it:

```
def runInParallel(*fns):
    proc = []
    for fn, arg in fns:
        p = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=arg)  # was args=(arg,)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

runInParallel((func1, (Variable1, Variable2,)),
              (func2, (Variable12, Variable22, Variable23,)))
```

Thanks to Mark Dickinson for correcting my correction. `;-)`

Comment: This does not pass the arguments in the runInParallel function and gives me the folowwing : "TypeError: func2() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)" . func1 and func2 do not have the same number of arguments..

Comment: You also need to change `args=(arg,)` to `args=arg` when you create the `Thread` objects.

Comment: Thanks ! It was a matter of commas... I will answer my question with your corrections .